Do lenders consider stocks and bonuses as part of your income?
Most tech companies give their employees a basic income plus a certain amount of stocks plus annual bonuses.
I am wondering if someone has a $120k salary + $50k stocks + $50k bonus in a year, would lenders consider this person's income as $220k/year or $120k/year? If they consider the $220k, this means he can apply for a loan that requires $9k/month payments, but if they only consider the basic $120k income, he will be approved for a loan with $5k/month.
PS: I am specifically asking for north California (Bay area) market.

My experience it that if you can show it to be consistently part of your income, then yes. Some banks have special deals for employees of some larger companies where they wave the tenure requirement. Anecdotally, I've been asked to provide 2 prior W2s to show consistency for these to be included in my income for mortgage consideration.

Just to share my experience, it varies from lender to lender. Some lenders are more conservative and are unwilling to consider bonuses and stocks; some lenders are willing to consider them, but with restrictions or discounts. If the stocks are private company stocks, as far as I know, almost no lender considers them as income. I'm not aware of any regulations that require lenders to consider or not consider them.

The lender will have to determine if they are comfortable about including overtime and bonuses when determining the expected monthly income. They want to to see that it is consistent over a period of 1 to 2 years. They will want to see recent pay stubs and tax forms for the last year or two.
The issue is what to do about awarded shares. They would have to determine if you actually own the shares and if they aren't just the right to buy the shares. They also need to know that you can and will sell the shares. Shares that can't be sold aren't income that can be used to pay the mortgage. Shares that can only be sold back to the company are hard to value.
If there are a lot of shares, the lender might wonder why you don't sell a bunch of them as a source of a larger down payment, and reduce the need for a mortgage. Of course you may have decided that the expected growth of the value of the shares doesn't make them a good candidate for a down payment; but that might make them also believe that you won't sell them to fund your monthly expenses.
